Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent "RNSScreenContentWrapper" was not found in UIManager
I encountered the following error while trying to run my React Native project:
Could not find method provided() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react-native:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenContentWrapper" was not found in the UIManager.
The issue seems to occur when navigating between screens using @react-navigation/native-stack.
Here are the steps I’ve taken so far:

Installed the required dependencies using npm install @react-navigation/native-stack react-native-screens.

Called enableScreens() in App.js.

Cleaned the cache using npm start --reset-cache.

Rebuilt the project using npx react-native run-android.


Despite these steps, the error persists. I’m also seeing a related build error:
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenContentWrapper" was not found in the UIManager.

Could not find method provided() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react-native:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
Additional Information:

React Native version: 0.76.3

Node version: v22.4.0.


Any insights on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Here are the steps I’ve taken so far:

Installed the required dependencies using npm install @react-navigation/native-stack react-native-screens.

Called enableScreens() in App.js.

Cleaned the cache using npm start --reset-cache.

Rebuilt the project using npx react-native run-android.


I expected the app to run without errors and navigate smoothly between screens. However, the error persists.
Additionally, I’m seeing this related build error:
Could not find method provided() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react-native:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

